# Set variable of enum type by string in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, enums

How to assign value to a variable of type enum in TypeScript?

Given

```
enum options { 'one' = 'one', 'two' = 'two', 'three' = 'three'}
let selected = options.one
```

I need to set variable "selected" by string value and the following function does the job well:

```
function setSelected (newOption: string): void {
  switch (newOption) {
    case 'one':
      selected = userThemePreferences.one
      break
    case 'two':
      selected = userThemePreferences.two
      break
    default:
      selected = userThemePreferences. three
      break
  }
}
```

Is it possible to write a function so that it will not be changed when enum items changes. In current function if we add 'four' to our enum we will need to add case to switch statement.
And that is what I want to avoid.

Comment: `selected = options[newOption]`. Also change the type of `newOption` to `newOption: keyof options`.

Comment: newOption is a string. If I cud provide newOption: keyof options but I can't. Incoming value is a string. And how to cast?

Comment: I just saw you want to handle the default case as well. In that case don't change the typing but do a typecast instead: `selected = options[newOption as any]`. Instead of any you could cast it to keyof options as well. Selected will be undefined if the option is not on the enum, so use that to handle the default case with `?? ` or `||`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use keyof typeof to convert string to enum. Below code will convert string to enum.

```
enum options { 'one' = 'one', 'two' = 'two', 'three' = 'three'}

let selected: options = options.one;
const newOption = "two";

console.log(selected); //prints "one"

selected = options[newOption as keyof typeof options];
// Handle if newOption is not a valid enum string
if(selected === undefined){
    selected = options.three;
}

console.log(selected); //prints "two"
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDcCmAnKBlKKCWYDmAKiAKJgCuAtjALwwBmZYwU24AFAJQBcMCI2AEwDeAKBjiYSclRAAHFuAgwhMAOTgkqmmo2qANGqgB3EFtqrjpgxYAWKJJu237mgL5iJAGySwISb8xIAjxyCpDaoayQAHQaANwe4vDQMGBIRgDy8lHaAESWuQkScIog3tGeIHhsfgFQQRxxMAD0zbI4YFBKuRq5iTD9tUiBAhHZigDaaZnjYDAAhkoA1kgAniB0MFCrskgbMJGKALpFEq0wABLzYALeMNib01lh90pgILDzvPOegpLSMGgHTw-QeNX8w3qo2oMJgjAESDouAaomKxSGIzGYQg0Sgdgcp3E7n6yTKSAqVXBdQaTVa7VwXRg%20RMfRExPgyDQmGBRFIlE4cSAA)